# JQuery toggle rows on click

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, expand

I'm trying to hide/show a subset of rows when clicking a row with a specific id.

Through a lot of searching the web and a lot of tries I got the code below.

Only problem is this code for some reason only hides/shows the very first set of rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<head>
           <title>Test</title>

           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

           <script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).ready(function()
             {
                 $('#rowToClick').click(function ()
                 {
                     $(this).nextAll('tr').each( function()
                     {
                         if ($(this).is('#rowToClick'))
                        {
                           return false;
                        }
                        $(this).toggle();
                     });
                 });
             });
           </script>
         </head>          

<body>
<table>
    <tr id="rowToClick"><td>ClickMe</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr1"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr2"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr3"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr4"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr5"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    <tr id="rowToClick"><td>ClickMe</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr6"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr7"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr8"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr9"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    <tr id="Tr10"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Anyone has a suggestion and/or possible rewrite of the code?

**---------- Update - Final solution -----------**

I ended up with the solution below based on Brandon's input, as I wanted to do more nesting with the same behaviour, kind of like a collapsible tree view.
Unfortunately that meant I had to add an extra attribute to keep track of the state, but I can live with that for now, until I find another way (ex. check visibility of the next row).

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
             toggleRows('.module','.namespace');
             toggleRows('.namespace','.type');
             toggleRows('.type','.member');
         });

         function toggleRows(parentClass,subClass)
         {
            $(parentClass).click(function () {

                if( $(this).attr("value")=="collapsed")                 
                {
                  $(this).attr("value","expanded");
                  $(this).nextUntil(parentClass).filter(subClass).toggle(true);
                }
                else
                {
                  $(this).attr("value","collapsed");
                  $(this).nextUntil(parentClass).attr("value","collapsed");
                  $(this).nextUntil(parentClass).toggle(false);
                }       

            });
         }
```

Comment: Have you thought of using a plugin such as tablesorter? http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/3/28/Finished-jQuery-Tablesorter-mod-for-Collapsible-Table-Rows

Comment: Use .data() instead of .attr().  Its more compliant:  `$(this).data("value")` and `$(this).data("value", "expanded")`.  Also, chain your calls to avoid scanning the DOM 2x: `$(this).nextUntil(parentClass).data("value","collapsed").toggle(false);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you cannot have multiple rows with the same id.  Instead of setting id to "rowToClick", set the css class:

```
<tr class='rowToClick'><td>click me</td></tr>
```

Next, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function()
         {
             $(".rowToClick").click(function() { $(this).nextUntil(".rowToClick").toggle(); });
         });
```

Answer (score 2):

this is because the id attribute can only be used once for each id in a document. you should use the class attribute instead, and then in your jquery code, access the items with the class rowToClick with the $(".rowToClick") selector.

Hope this helps.

Andy

Answer (score 2):

- Take a look **[at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nogoodatcoding/6gKNH/1/)**
  Using the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector, you can select all `tr` elements that do not have the id/class you want filtered out:

  ```
  $('.rowToClick').click(function ()
  {
      $('tr:not(.rowToClick)').toggle(); 
      //toggle all rows on the page that 
      //do not have the class rowToClick
  });
  ```
- Note that you cannot have two elements with the same id - you have two rows with the id `rowToClick`. Use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**I believe this is the desired behavior:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="Includes/JavaScript/jQuery/version1.4.4/Core/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            // Also, just as an extra, use "context" to limit the scope of any jQuery selector-search.
            // That way on large pages your selector doesn't search through the whole page,
            // it only searches the tables HTML.
            // Doing so is a short-cut for: $('#tblMyTable').find('tr.clickTrigger');
            var context = $('#tblMyTable'); 

            $('tr.clickTrigger', context).click(function() {

                $(this).nextAll('tr').each(function() {

                    if ($(this).is('tr.clickTrigger'))
                        return false;

                    $(this).toggle();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table id="tblMyTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="clickTrigger">
                <td>ClickMe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr1">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr2">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr3">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr4">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr5">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="clickTrigger">
                <td>ClickMe</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr6">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr7">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr8">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr9">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="Tr10">
                <td>Toggled</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch your code to something like this:

```
<tr class="rowToClick" rel="1"><td>ClickMe</td></tr>
<tr class="row1Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
<tr class="row1Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
<tr class="row1Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
<tr class="row1Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
<tr class="row1Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
<tr class="rowToClick" rel="2"><td>ClickMe</td></tr>
<tr class="row2Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
<tr class="row2Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
<tr class="row2Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
<tr class="row2Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
<tr class="row2Collapse"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
```

Then, something like this:

```
$('.rowToClick').click(function()
{
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');

    $('.row' + rel + 'Collapse').show(); // or hide, you get the idea
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function padre(id){
                         var pa=$('.rowToClick_'+id);
                         $(pa).nextAll('tr').each( function(){
                            if ($(this).is('.rowToClickEnd_'+id))
                            {
                                $(this).toggle();
                                return false;
                            }
                            $(this).toggle();
                        });   
                     }
               </script>

    <table>
        <tr class="rowToClick_1"><td><a href="javascript:padre('1')">+</a>Categoria 1</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr1" class="rowToClick_1_1"><td><a href="javascript:padre('1_1')">+</a>Categoria 1_1</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr1_1"><td>Categoria 1_1_1</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr1_2" class="rowToClickEnd_1_1"><td>Categoria 1_1_2</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr2"><td>Categoria 1_2</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr3"><td>Categoria 1_3</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr4"><td>Categoria 1_4</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr5" class="rowToClickEnd_1"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
        <tr class="rowToClick"><td>ClickMe</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr6"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr7"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr8"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr9"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
        <tr id="Tr10" class="rowToClickEnd"><td>Toggled</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: It applies for different levels

Comment: add some info about how your answer works. it will help others.